# If $\int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx <\infty$, then does $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_n^{n+1}\sqrt{f(x)}\, dx = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Here, $f$ is a non-negative continuous function.

I first noted that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx <\infty \implies \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_n^{n+1}f(x)\, dx = 0
$$

From here, it seems intuitive that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_n^{n+1}\sqrt{f(x)}\, dx = 0$, but I can't make any progress.

I'm looking for a hint on how to proceed next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the inequality $$\int_{n}^{n+1} \sqrt{f(x)} \, dx \le \left( \int_n^{n+1} f(x) \, dx \right)^{1/2}.$$